# Dertermine whether indexes in Mysql work or not

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I had a table that has index is **index(a,b)** with a, b are two columns of my table.

I made a query like :

```
select * from **table** 
where
    ( a = a1 and b = b1) or
    ( a = a2 and b = b2) or
    ...
    ( a = a40 and b = b40)
```

My question is Does my index works on this situation ?
Thanks everyone

Comment: Try it on your data and see if it works.  I would expect it to, though.

Comment: 1) Investigate [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html) for your query. 2) Simplify the query into `select * from table where ( a, b ) IN ( (a1, b1) , ( a2, b2), ... ( a40, b40) )`.

Comment: *Does my index works on this situation ?* Depends on data statistic. Maybe yes, maybe no. EXPLAIN may show.

Comment: Akina's rewrite _works efficiently on newer versions of MySQL only_.  For old versions it, and your or/and approach is performed as a tedious table scan.  See "Row Constructor" in MySQL 5.7.3.